# Android Linear Gradient Drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, gradient

I want to make `GradientDrawable` for background like the image below.

[image]

`Linear Gradient` with **same** color in the **top** and **bottom**.

I made `gradient drawable` with `start`, `center` and `end` colors but couldn't set the size of center color.

I also tried `<Layer-list>` with 2 gradient shape-s but one overlays over the other and either I have gradient on the top or on the bottom.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: use "rect" `ShapeDrawable` + `ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory`

Comment: dont you know how to use `ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory` ?

Comment: @pskink I get the same effect as I had with xml gradient. I can't make center color dominant to take about 80% of screen

Comment: yes you can, just use 4 colors and 4 positions in `LinearGradient` constructor

Comment: @pskink wow Thanks man, I didn't know you could use 4 colors, post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use "rect" type `ShapeDrawable` and `ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory`

when implementing `ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory` return the `LinearGradient` using `colors` array with 4 colors (f.ex: white, dark_blue, dark_blue, white) and `positions` array with 4 positions (f.ex: 0, 0.2, 0.8, 1)